# Testing vimdiff with Vader

Tags: vim, automated-tests, vim-plugin

I am writing a vim plugin and I am testing it with the [Vader framework](https://github.com/junegunn/vader.vim).  One of the features is a diff feature.  I've tested it manually and it appears to work but I would like to test it automatically using the framework. Is this realistic?  How would I do it?